# Bands shift in PyProcar and quantum espresso

Tags: quantum-espresso, pyprocar

Using the same inputs in [here](https://github.com/matbinder/pyprocar-example/blob/master/pyprocar.ipynb) I re-implemented the band structure and projected density of state calculations using Quantum Espresso, then I used the same command:

```
import pyprocar
pyprocar.bandsplot(code='qe',mode='plain', elimit=[-18,-8])
```

to plot the bands using PyProcar, I get:

[image]

Which is clearly different from the original one [here](https://github.com/matbinder/pyprocar-example/blob/master/pyprocar.ipynb). It seems to me the bands have been shifted by 2E_F.

Is there any explanation?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem and solved it just by setting the Fermi level to 0 eV.
`pyprocar.bandsplot(code = 'qe', mode='plain',repair = False,color="r",elimit=[-1,1],fermi = 0.000)`

Hope that helps!